# How Impedance triangle is formed?

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, passive-networks

I know how voltage triangle is formed for RL circuit. But I am not understanding how impedance triangle is formed. Is it derived from voltage triangle ? If so, how it is derived from voltage triangle ? 
Please don't tell that divide each side of voltage triangle with current 'I' to form impedance triangle . I want more generalised explanation

[image]

Comment: All right, we won't tell you.

Comment: The voltage triangle is derived from the impedance triangle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector math.

In a series RL circuit, current **I** is same through both **R** and **L**. It will be in some phase with respect to the supply source **V**.

Voltage, Current, Impedance can be represented as vectors as they have both magnitude as well as phase.

- First you need a reference vector. I disregard the supply and its phase and take voltage drop across R, \$V_R\$ vector as the reference. So I can represent it as a horizontal line.

  Then current vector will be in the same line as both are in phase in a resistor.
  (\$\vec {V_R}\angle 0,\vec I\angle 0\$)

[image]

- Since the same current flows through L, the current vector of L is the same as  R. In Inductor, current and voltage have 90 degree phase shift between each other.

  (\$\vec {V_L}\angle 90,\vec I\angle 0\$)

[image]

The result is the familiar voltage triangle of RL circuit.

[image]

Now you can straight forward deduce the impedance vectors.

$$\frac{\vec {V_R}\angle0}{\vec I\angle 0} = R \angle 0$$
$$\frac{\vec {V_L}\angle90}{\vec I\angle 0} = X_R \angle 90$$

Result is the impedance triangle similar to voltage triangle.

[image]

Comment: Why resistance is the reference vector in impedance triangle , why not reactance as reference?

Comment: Thats Your wish which one to be taken as reference ..........

Comment: I have read from other sources that only constant vector is taken as reference, so in voltage triangle current is taken as reference since it is a constant vector in series RL circuit. So, this should be applied to impedance triangle also. I think R is also constant vector, because it does not change through out AC analysis. But what about reactance, is it changes with respect to time or does not change with time.

Comment: What is a 'constant vector' by the way , while current is changing here every moment. You are wrong. You can take any vector as reference to obtain a right triangle every time.  --  Vector Mathematics